# Simulate touch jquery mobile

Tags: javascript, android, jquery

I want to know how to simulate the touch of a tablet / smartphone device. The transaction is expected to click automatically when the page is a div with the inclusion in number input, so as to immediately open the numeric keypad on the device for the insertion of values. Pc runs on the function:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#id_campo_input').trigger('click'); 
});
```

But on mobile devices does not open the keypad .. If I apply the function to a normal div href with the click works well ...

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to click, you need to set autofocus on that field(implies that keyboard will be opened).

Read this for more details: 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_autofocus.asp